# Not able to create connection on oracle sql developer tool

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a new connection on the Oracle SQL Developer tool but I'm not able to. I just simply download the latest version of oracle SQL developer tool from the oracle site and unzip the folder and run. I haven't set any password or anything because there is nothing to do so.

Please guide how I can make a local connection on oracle Sql developer tool.

Comment: Did you install the Oracle database? SQL Developer is just a client application; it is not a full database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well based on what you have described, you only installed SQL Developer, without having the Oracle Client installed on your device.

To be able to connec to to something in SQL Developer, you need to have a database to which you would like to connect. That basically means that either you need to install one, or you have one available in your System. But I will assume that you are new to this and have no database to connect to.

First things first, you will need to install the Oracle Client. A pretty good example can be found on [here](http://www.rebellionrider.com/how-to-install-oracle-database-12c-on-windows-7-8/). You have a video tutorial which contains a step by step guide.

Once you finished installing the Oracle Client, you can proceed with unlocking the basic HR Schema, or create your own DB Schema. Again, a tutorial on how to achieve this step can be found [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-unlock-hr-schema-in-oracle-12c-or-how-to-fix-the-ora-01033-error/).

There are a few steps to follow, but in the end, if you follow them accordingly, you will be able to make a local connection on oracle using SQL Developer. Besides that, both the links will provide you with some explanation as well for each particular task.